# Working with small decimal points in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working with decimal points but Javascript seems to be rounding down all the time.

For example, here's one of the calculations I need done:

(1 + 0.05) ^ (1/12)

This should return 1.0040741237836483016054196026721 however all I'm getting is 1.

I've tried using the Big.js library but it's still only returning me 1 and I need those decimal points to have an accurate result, is there a way to specify the number of decimal positions I want?

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript you're using to do the calculation?

Comment: Check out [decimal.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/). It might be more of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` symbol has **bitwise XOR** semantics in javascript. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_XOR_assignment).

The following code snippet shows you how to obtain the correct result:

```js
console.log(`(1 + 0.05) ^ (1/12) = ${Math.pow((1 + 0.05), (1/12))}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in another answer, you can use vanilla JS but if you need to perform mathematical operations with precision than you can look into libraries like [decimal.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) to aid with maintaining that precision.

```js
const vanJS = Math.pow(1 + 0.05, 1/12);
const decJS = Decimal.pow(1 + 0.05, 1/12).toPrecision(20);

console.log({ vanJS, decJS });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/10.0.1/decimal.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always use **[Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)** (MDN oficial source) Library to make calculations. You can use `Pow(val, exponential)` function to your advantage.

If you have 1/2 then you can say it's 2^(-1). This way you can always translate a **division** to an **exponential**

Javascript has some issues with precision, and you will have a hard time dealing with floating points.

```js
var amount  = (1 + 0.05) ^ (1/12);
var amountPow = Math.pow(1 + 0.05, Math.pow(12,-1));
console.log((1 + 0.05) ^ (1/12)); // Normal
console.log(amountPow); // Exponential function Math
```

Comment: `Math.pow` actually works with real exponents as well. So, your second `Math.pow` call is not wrong but unnecessary since `Math.pow(1 + 0.05, 1/12) === Math.pow(1 + 0.05, Math.pow(12, -1))`.

Comment: This is my point: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/avoiding-problems-with-decimal-math-in-javascript.html             - " Division of integers and multiplication by decimals may still result in inexact values, but basic integer addition, subtraction, and multiplication will be accurate"

Comment: I don't see how your post states that, tbh. Your code does not deal with the floating point precision problem. Also, precision problems are not limited to JavaScript. For example: `200.30 * 3 != 600.90 # True` in Python 3.